# Angular 7 Routing

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing

I am receiving an error on my Angular 7 Application

And here is the error.

> Error: Invalid configuration of route 'dashboard'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

I am creating a Time in and Time out Application using Angular 7.

I already have my asp.net core web API which handles the login and it worked as expected.

Then I decided to add a `dashboard` and `employees`

[image]

Then I added routes.ts file

And this is the code for the class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Then I modified the app.module.ts file

and added

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Then I also added this code in the `imports array`

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
```

But upon reloading the Angular 7 application just in case to check if it has an error.

> main.ts:12 Error: Invalid configuration of route 'dashboard'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren
>           at validateNode (router.js:607)
>           at validateConfig (router.js:577)
>           at Router.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.Router.resetConfig (router.js:4108)
>           at new Router (router.js:3784)
>           at setupRouter (router.js:5567)
>           at _callFactory (core.js:21292)
>           at *createProviderInstance (core.js:21238)
>           at initNgModule (core.js:21168)
>           at new NgModuleRef* (core.js:21895)
>           at createNgModuleRef (core.js:21884)

What is the cause of this? And can someone guide me on how to solve this?

I already tried searching for a solution and tried the one that works for them but the error is still there. What do I need in order to make this work?

This is the `app-routing.module.ts` code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My expected output for this is it doesn\t have an error so i can redirect to the dashboard component when the login is succesfull

And this is the code for app.component.html

```
<app-login></app-login> 
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Thank you very much.

Thus us

Comment: what is the value of appRoutes here, can you edit your question ??

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @NiraliPatel hello. I have updated the question. I added the app-routing.module.ts code

Comment: ok good, now you can check, the current answers will help you

Comment: @Ramonbihon Provide the app.module.ts code cause I think problem is in that module!

Answer (score 0):

you must create app.routing.ts file with routes, is my example for you:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Import Containers
import { DefaultLayoutComponent } from './containers';

import { LoginComponent } from './views/login/login.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Login Page'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'crm',
        loadChildren: './views/crm/crm.module#CrmModule'
      },
   ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

error itself saying that you have to provide  `component`, `redirectTo`, `children` or `loadChildren` property to the appRoute object of where you define routes,

So here you must be missing to add any one of above.

example

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

const routes: appRoutes = [
  { path: 'alerts', loadChildren: './components/alerts/alerts.module#AlertsModule' },
  { path: 'settings/assets', loadChildren: './components/settings/assets/assets.module#AssetsModule' },
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './components/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
  { path: 'reports', loadChildren: './components/reports/reports.module#ReportsModule' },
  { path: 'settings/alert', loadChildren: './components/settings/alert/alert.module#AlertModule' },
  { path: 'settings/control-framework', loadChildren: './components/settings/control-framework/control-framework.module#ControlFrameworkModule' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```